Simplifying Eliminating Duplicate Columns SQL
I have the following code:
update tble
set 
offer_id_02 = offer_id_03,
offer_id_03 = offer_id_04,
offer_id_04 = offer_id_05,
offer_id_05 = offer_id_06,
offer_id_06 = offer_id_07,
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_02 = offer_id_01;


update tble
set 
offer_id_03 = offer_id_04,
offer_id_04 = offer_id_05,
offer_id_05 = offer_id_06,
offer_id_06 = offer_id_07,
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_03 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_03 = offer_id_02; 


update tble
set 
offer_id_04 = offer_id_05,
offer_id_05 = offer_id_06,
offer_id_06 = offer_id_07,
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_04 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_04 = offer_id_02 or offer_id_04 = offer_id_03;


update tble
set 
offer_id_05 = offer_id_06,
offer_id_06 = offer_id_07,
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_05 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_05 = offer_id_02 or offer_id_05 = offer_id_03 or offer_id_05 = offer_id_04;


update tble
set 
offer_id_06 = offer_id_07,
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_06 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_06 = offer_id_02 or offer_id_06 = offer_id_03 or offer_id_06 = offer_id_04 or offer_id_06 = offer_id_05;


update tble
set 
offer_id_07 = offer_id_08,
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_07 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_07 = offer_id_02 or offer_id_07 = offer_id_03 or offer_id_07 = offer_id_04 or offer_id_07 = offer_id_05  or offer_id_07 = offer_id_06;



update tble
set 
offer_id_08 = NULL
where offer_id_08 = offer_id_01 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_02 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_03 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_04 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_05 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_06 or offer_id_08 = offer_id_07;

I tried to simplify the logic to the below but found that the duplicates just go to different columns. For example, if the duplicates existed between offer_id_01 and offer_id_02, after running the below code, it would just become a duplicate between offer_id_02 and offer_id_03. But the above code works as intended ( I essentially want to eliminate all duplicates and am okay with slot offer_id_08 being null)
UPDATE tble
SET
    OFFER_ID_02 = CASE 
                    WHEN offer_id_02 = offer_id_01 THEN offer_id_03
                    ELSE offer_id_02
                  END,
    OFFER_ID_03 = CASE 
                    WHEN offer_id_03 = offer_id_01 OR offer_id_03 = offer_id_02 THEN offer_id_04 
                    ELSE offer_id_03
                  END,
    OFFER_ID_04 = CASE 
                    WHEN offer_id_04 = offer_id_01 OR offer_id_04 = offer_id_02 OR offer_id_04 = offer_id_03 THEN offer_id_05 
                    ELSE offer_id_04
                  END,
    OFFER_ID_05 = CASE 
                    WHEN offer_id_05 = offer_id_01 OR offer_id_05 = offer_id_02 OR offer_id_05 = offer_id_03 OR offer_id_05 = offer_id_04 THEN offer_id_06 
                    ELSE offer_id_05
                  END,
    OFFER_ID_06 = CASE 
                    WHEN offer_id_06 = offer_id_01 OR offer_id_06 = offer_id_02 OR offer_id_06 = offer_id_03 OR offer_id_06 = offer_id_04 OR offer_id_06 = offer_id_05 THEN offer_id_07 
                    ELSE offer_id_06
                  END,
    OFFER_ID_07 = CASE 
                    WHEN offer_id_07 = offer_id_01 OR offer_id_07 = offer_id_02 OR offer_id_07 = offer_id_03 OR offer_id_07 = offer_id_04 OR offer_id_07 = offer_id_05 OR offer_id_07 = offer_id_06 THEN offer_id_08 
                    ELSE offer_id_07
                  END,
    OFFER_ID_08 = CASE 
                    WHEN offer_id_08 = offer_id_01 OR offer_id_08 = offer_id_02 OR offer_id_08 = offer_id_03 OR offer_id_08 = offer_id_04 OR offer_id_08 = offer_id_05 OR offer_id_08 = offer_id_06 OR offer_id_08 = offer_id_07 THEN null
                    ELSE offer_id_08
                  END

Any idea on why this simplification does not work? Or any other suggestions on how I can simplify this logic?

You would need to nest your case statement, quite grotesquely, to do it all in one go. Reason is that when they run in sequence, the value of offer_id_02 already has the first operations logic applied.

@Error_2646 I am confused on why that is. Because for example if 1 and 2 are equal to each other, the first update will essentially make 1 and 3 equal to each other, and the next case statement would take care of that and then all the way up until offer_id_08 where it just becomes null.
On a seperate note, would nesting it all be within the first case statment and keep nexting it all the way through?
